# Is reverse proxy server a requirement for Exchange 2010 with Outlook Anywhere?

Tags: exchange, reverse-proxy, exchange-2010, outlook-anywhere

We are planning to install Outlook Anywhere in Exchange 2010.

Microsoft seems to suggest there is a proxy server required in the diagram in here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-outlook-anywhere-to-connect-to-your-exchange-server-without-vpn-ae01c0d6-8587-4055-9bc9-bbd5ca15e817 but did not talk much about it.

Dans course http://danscourses.com/category/courses/exchange-server/ did not mention about the proxy server at all.

Can someone please enlighten me on this?

Comment: I think Mikael has given very a very clear answer, and if you want to learn more about reverse proxy in Exchange, you can refer to the reply in this case: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/392907-reverse-proxy-for-exchange-2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to turn on Outlook Anywhere without installing a reversing proxy server.

The steps I took were:

1) Enable Outlook Anywhere in CAS server

2) Create external DNS CNAME record for autodiscover.domain.name to point to the CAS server.

That's it.  The same Outlook profile can be used inside and outside the domain.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a requirement, but it's a nice way of lessening the impact of (CAS) downtime if you're running an Exchange cluster. If you're not, a reverse proxy may still give you an additional layer of defense, if configured to do so. However, if that's not part of the plan I'd say it's just another moving part that needs understanding and maintenance, so you're likely better off with sane firewall rules as per the KISS principle.

That said: If you do run multiple Exchange servers behind a reverse proxy/load balancer, upgrading to 2013 or newer will give your clients a much nicer experience in case of failure: Connections in newer Exchange versions are stateless to a degree the 2010 version couldn't achieve, and so losing a host should be more or less imperceptible to the user.